# How to limit mysql search result from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, how can I select only the rows of a table where a column value matches one of the values found in another query from other tables?

Here again a bit clearer:
I'm using `GTFS (General Transit Feed Specification)` data which describes stations, stop times, routes and so on of public transport system

I' trying to get ALL stop times of ONE train route at a specific train station.

I have the following tables:

```
 - stop-times: contains columns: 'stop-time', 'station id', 'trip id'
 - trips: contains columns:'trip id', 'route-id'
 - routes: contains columns: 'route-id', 'route-name'
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)?

Comment: No, i'm a complete beginner and was not sure where to start searching for a solution... JOIN, HAVING, SUB-SELECT... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having much information, I guess

```
select
    r.'route-id',
    s.'station id',
    s.'stop-time'
from
    routes r
inner join
    trips t
on
    r.'route-id' = t.'route-id'
inner join
    stop-times s
on
    t.'trip id' = s.'trip id'
where
    r.'route-name' = 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME'
and
    s.'station id' = YOUR_STATION_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! I'm trying to undertand the principle :)